# What is the best way to refer to a static method from another static method of the same class in Rust?

Tags: module, rust, static-methods

In a new Rust module, I can write:

```
struct myStruct {
    x : u32
}

impl myStruct {
    fn new() -> myStruct{
        myStruct{ x : other()}
    }

    fn other() -> u32 {
        6
    }
}
```

Coming from other OO languages, I would expect `other()` to be in scope for `new()`. That is, I would expect to be able to call one static method of a class from another static method of the same class. However, rustc produces the message:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `other` in this scope
 --> dummy_module.rs:9:23
  |
9 |         myStruct{ x : other()}
  |                       ^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

In contrast, the following Java code compiles fine:

```java
public class myStruct{
    int x;

    public myStruct(){
        x = other();
    }

    private int other(){
        return 5;
    }
}
```

I don't recall seeing any mention of this in the Rust book I'm using, and I can't seem to find a clear answer online. I can fix it by explicitly scoping the call to other with `myStruct::other()`, but this seems cumbersome. If I try `use myStruct`, then I get the cryptic message

```
7 |     use myStruct;
  |     ^^^ unexpected token
```

Is this explicit scoping always required? If so, why?

Am I doing something incorrect? Is there an idiomatic workaround to this?

Comment: Rust isn't really an "OO" language in the same way that Java is. If you try to write Java in Rust, you're going to run into a lot of issues.

Comment: And this has nothing linked to OO language this is just a question about grammar.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Rust designers have made the following choice: everything related to the scope is explicit. So, just as you must type `self` to call a member function from another member function: `self.foo()`, you must call a static member with `Self`: `Self::bar()`.

I think that it is the case because `self` could not be implicit: indeed it had to be added as a parameter either by value or borrowed, unlike in Java where `this` is always taken by value. Thus, because `self` was already an explicit parameter, it was needed as an explicit caller for consistency.

Because of its memory model, Rust expliciteness permit to give better error messages. For example, consider this code:

```
struct Struct;

impl Struct {
    fn foo(&mut self) {
        self.consume();
    }

    fn consume(self) {}
}
```

The error message is:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
5 |         self.consume();
  |         ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Then the team made the choice of full expliciteness to maintain the grammar coherent.

Comment: I cannot find any proof of what I say. The explicit `self` was implemented back to 2012: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/3974 and there were no RFCs at this time.

Comment: Note that other languages (eg. Python) had an explicit `self` parameter for methods long before Rust came along, which may have influenced the design of Rust.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is intended, because rust is not Java ;)

You just can write:

```
myStruct { x: myStruct::other() }
```

or

```
myStruct { x: Self::other() }
```

I can't tell you the exact design decision, why `Self` functions are not imported automatically, but you can "work-around" this, by using the correct path.